# How to internationalize angular app using i18n

Tags: angularjs, internationalization, angular-i18n

Recently i got to internationalize my angular app. I heard about (i18n) and i have no idea about it but i am interested to go through it.
   Can anyone please suggest me some good articles regarding it.Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

[Angular translate](https://angular-translate.github.io/) is your friend.